404 Error when Serving Files Outside of public Directory in Next.js 14
I'm building a Next.js 14 app running in a Docker container where users can upload images. These images are stored outside the public folder in Server/uploads (shared via Samba on my home server), and I need them to be immediately available during runtime without having to rebuild the app. I'm using Apache as a reverse proxy to serve the images, but when trying to access them, I get a 404 error even though I see the image get successfully uploaded to the correct folder.
Image Upload Route:
// Set the base upload directory on the server-side
const baseUploadPath = path.join(__dirname, "../uploads");

if (!fs.existsSync(baseUploadPath)) {
  fs.mkdirSync(baseUploadPath, { recursive: true });
}

// Multer storage setup for image uploads
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    const userUploadPath = path.join(baseUploadPath, req.user.id.toString()); // Create user-specific folder
    if (!fs.existsSync(userUploadPath)) {
      fs.mkdirSync(userUploadPath, { recursive: true });
    }
    cb(null, userUploadPath); // Save to user-specific folder
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, Date.now() + "-" + file.originalname); // Unique filename
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

// Create a new spot (Protected Route)
router.post("/", authMiddleware, upload.single("image"), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { spotName, description, location } = req.body;

    // Ensure location exists and split into latitude and longitude
    if (!location) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        message:
          "Location is required and should be in 'latitude, longitude' format.",
      });
    }

    const [latitude, longitude] = location
      .split(",")
      .map((coord) => parseFloat(coord.trim()));

    if (isNaN(latitude) || isNaN(longitude)) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        message: "Invalid coordinates format. Use 'latitude, longitude'.",
      });
    }

    // Generate the relative path for the image (e.g., /uploads/userId/image.jpg)
    const imagePath = req.file
      ? `/uploads/${req.user.id}/${req.file.filename}`
      : null;

    // Create the new spot
    const newSpot = await Spot.create({
      spotName,
      description,
      location,
      latitude,
      longitude,
      image: imagePath,
      userId: req.user.id, // Authenticated user ID
    });

    res.status(201).json(newSpot);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Failed to add the spot" });
  }
});

Here is my apache2 conf file:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName caligo.site
    ServerAlias www.caligo.site

    ProxyPreserveHost On

    # Update all backend routes to include /api prefix
    ProxyPass "/api/auth" "http://localhost:3001/api/auth"
    ProxyPassReverse "/api/auth" "http://localhost:3001/api/auth"

    ProxyPass "/api/comments" "http://localhost:3001/api/comments"
    ProxyPassReverse "/api/comments" "http://localhost:3001/api/comments"

    ProxyPass "/api/spots" "http://localhost:3001/api/spots"
    ProxyPassReverse "/api/spots" "http://localhost:3001/api/spots"

    ProxyPass "/api/users" "http://localhost:3001/api/users"
    ProxyPassReverse "/api/users" "http://localhost:3001/api/users"

    # Serve the uploads directory directly
    Alias "/uploads" "/home/sambauser/shared_folder/web servers/CaliGo/Server/uploads"
    <Directory "/home/sambauser/shared_folder/web servers/CaliGo/Server/uploads">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    EnableMMAP off

    # Route all other paths to frontend on port 3000
    ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:3000/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:3000/"

</VirtualHost>

Issues:

The uploaded images are not accessible via the /uploads route and result in a 404 error.
The files are stored on my home server using Samba for file sharing, and the Apache server is configured to serve them.

Here is my Dockerfile in my client folder:
# Dockerfile for Next.js frontend
# Use the official Node.js image
FROM node:18-alpine

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Set environment variable for production
ENV NODE_ENV=production

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json
COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install 

# Copy the rest of the application code
COPY . .

# Build the Next.js app
RUN npm run build

# Expose the port Next.js runs on
EXPOSE 3000

# Start the Next.js app
CMD ["npm", "start"]

And here is my Server Dockerfile:
# Dockerfile for Node.js backend
FROM node:18-alpine

# Install dependencies for bcrypt on Alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache python3 make g++

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .

# Expose the backend port
EXPOSE 3001

# Wait for MySQL to be available, then start the server
CMD /bin/sh -c "while ! nc -z mysql 3306; do echo 'Waiting for MySQL...'; sleep 3; done && node server.js"

Finally here's my docker-compose file:
version: "3.8"

services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    env_file:
      - .env  # Use .env for environment variables
    depends_on:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ./client/public:/app/public  # Map the frontend public folder for static assets

  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql  # Persistent storage for MySQL database
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"

  backend:
    build:
      context: ./Server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    env_file:
      - .env  # Use .env for environment variables
    volumes:
      - ./Server/uploads:/app/uploads  # Persistent storage for uploaded images in backend
    depends_on:
      - mysql

volumes:
  mysql_data:  # Persistent storage for MySQL data

What I've tried:

Ensuring that the file permissions are correct on the uploads directory.
Testing the route with direct access to the images outside the container, which also results in a 404 error.

Additional Info:

The app is running on a home server using Samba for file sharing.
Apache is configured as a reverse proxy to serve the frontend and backend.
The images are stored outside the Next.js public folder but are being uploaded to the server's uploads directory, which is shared via Samba.

